# Doxygen - any way to get a module hierarchy?

Tags: doxygen

It seems that even if I specify my groups as follows:

```
@defgroup MainGroup
@brief ...

@defgroup SubGroup1
@brief ...
@ingroup MainGroup

@defgroup SubGroup2
@brief ...
@ingroup SubGroup1
```

The hierarchy in the "Modules" chapter isn't being respected by doxygen in the latex output (rendered as PDF): all the groups are treated as modules in **the same** level:

```
Modules
  MainGroup
  SubGroup1
  SubGroup2
```

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Could you be clearer whether this is a doxygen structure problem or a doxygen LaTex problem?  i.e. if you output as HTML does the same problem occur?

Comment: doxygen latex problem, the html looks fine

Comment: Very unfortunately, for me HTML does NOT look fine. The list of modules is flat just like the original asker describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you laid out references to these groups on pages you could make a [tree view of the pages](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsubpage).  Or sections can go down a couple levels of tree (section, [subsection](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsubsection) and subsubsection).  But I don't believe there is a specific way to set subgroups other than the [default subgroups](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdnosubgrouping).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in doxygen's latex generator. I found a bug report here:

https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/842

So I think the only way to solve this problem is fixing the bug itself.